# addition of unsigned offset

Tags: c++, runtime

So I was solving a problem on LeetCode in which Input: ["flower","flow","flight"]
Output: "fl" .. so I figured out a solution and worked perfectly on my local Visual Studio compiler but when I submitted it to the server the server complain with the following message "Line 924: Char 34: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x6030000000a0 overflowed to 0x603000000080 (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:933:34"

and to clarify the problem furthermore this is the problem link on LeetCode
[Longest Common Prefix](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-common-prefix/)
my solution is

```
string longestCommonPrefix(vector<string>  strs) 
{
    
    string temp;        
    int count = 0;
    int new_count = 0;
    string::iterator iter1;
    string::iterator iter2;

    for (int i = 0; i != strs.size(); ++i) {        
        
        if (i != str.size() - 1) {
            cout << "if 1\n";
            iter1 = strs[i].begin();
            iter2 = strs[i + 1].begin();
            
            while (iter1 != str[i].end() && iter2 != str[i + 1].end()) {
                 
                if (*iter1 == *iter2 ) {
                    temp.push_back(*iter1);
                    ++count;
                }
                
                if (*iter1 != *iter2)                   
                    break;              

                ++iter1;
                ++iter2;
            }
        }

        if (i == str.size() - 1) {
                        
            iter1 = strs[i].begin();
            iter2 = strs[i - 1].begin();

            while (iter1 != str[i].end() && iter2 != str[i - 1].end()) {

                if (*iter1 == *iter2 ) {
                    temp.push_back(*iter1);
                    ++new_count;
                }

                if (*iter1 != *iter2)                   
                    break;
                

                ++iter1;
                ++iter2;
            }

            break;
        }


        i += 1;     
    }

    new_count = min(count, new_count);

    

    if ( new_count == 0) {
        return "";
    }

    temp = string(temp.substr(0, new_count));

    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Where is the failing test case?

Comment: I'm having trouble following this code. Could you rename `str` to something like `strs` at least so it's easier to see as a vector of strings, and can you describe your algorithm in English before the code block?

Comment: There's a sneaky `i += 1;` there, while you also do `++i` in the for loop... because you check `i != str.size()` there's a chance you overshoot... imho this is a simple typo... thus question should be closed.

Comment: Regardless of whether you got the wrong answer or not, the code does not blow up when running [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/537360d7eb1fa5f6), given the test you are showing us.  So is that test the failing case?

Comment: If you have the input which causes the problem, then you can also create a program using that input hard-coded, and use a debugger to catch the crash to see when and where it happens in your code, and examine the values of all involved variables. You can also use the debugger to step through the code statement by statement to make sure it does what you're really expect it to do.

Comment: @JohnFilleau OK I already did this

Comment: @Alaa1991 I appreciate the `str` --> `strs` change, but the bigger issue was the lack of explanation of your algorithm before the code. I couldn't follow your logic. The problem seems solved now anyway. If you're feeling generous you might still include the algorithm, but you're under no obligation to.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie this test works perfectly on my local machine and it also works on LeetCode server when I hit run code button and it accept it, but when I SUBMIT it to the server it gives me that vague error without any indication about the failing test

Comment: Submitting will run several test cases.  Are you sure that the testcase that fails is not given to you?  Leetcode is one of the few that does give you the failing test case.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I already run the code on my local machine without any issues the problem arises when I submit my solution to the server it gives me this vague error message without any hints or indication to the failing test

Comment: @Alaa1991 -- No.  When you submit the code, all sorts of test cases are run against your code, not just the simple one given to you.  So you cannot assume your Visual Studio code has no issues.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes  I am sure cause it's complaining about "runtime error" not "wrong answer" if it was a wrong answer in that case it would show the failing test. is there anyway that I can screenshot the error message and share it with you?

Comment: @Alaa1991 -- That is not how C++ works.  If you have accessed an element out-of-bounds, then the code will produce undefined behavior, which could include a complete program crash, and not just give a "wrong answer".  C++ is not Java or Python.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie "When you submit the code, all sorts of test cases are run against your code" how can I see all these test cases on LeetCode? it only giving me two example and when I checking it on my local machine everything is fine. so is there a way to see all the test cases?

Comment: Leetcode has the test case available.  The last time I looked, it came along with the error.

Comment: If LeetCode does not give you the test case, I have a C++ string [fuzzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzing) that produces random string data.  If you go back to the Visual Studio version of your program, you may see that it will blow up for some input values.

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63046559/code-submission-on-spoj-gives-runtime-error-sigabrt/63048464#63048464).  I took the code at the link, and ran it on [this code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9100158c9f6b5c73).  It blows up if there is only one item in the vector.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you so much Paul you were right there were other test cases which failed one of them you already mentioned. right now I am on my way to fix all the failing test cases. your comments helped a lot thank you so much for taking the time to reply back to me

Answer (score 0):

This'll pass through, not sure about the bug though:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>

struct Solution {
    static std::string longestCommonPrefix(
        const std::vector<std::string>& strs
    ) {
        std::string longest = "";

        for (std::size_t letter = 0; std::size(strs) > 0; longest += strs[0][letter], ++letter) {
            for (std::size_t word = 0; word < std::size(strs); ++word) {
                if (
                    letter >= std::size(strs[word]) ||
                    (word > 0 && strs[word][letter] != strs[word - 1][letter])
                ) {
                    return longest;
                }
            }
        }

        return longest;
    }
};
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-common-prefix/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to solve the problem but that wasn't my intention to get a solution from stackoverflow community my intention was to figure out what went wrong. thank you so much