# Dynamic Programming solution doesn't work in Hackerrank enviroment

Tags: c++

My code runs perfectly on my machine but it fails even in the sample testcases on [Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/max-array-sum/problem). How can the same code yield different results on two different environment?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int maxum(int arr[], int n)
{
    int t[100][100];
    for(int i=0;i<n+1; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<n+1;j++)
        {
            if(i==0)
                t[i][j]=0;
            else
                t[i][j]=max(t[i-1][j]+arr[i-1], t[i-1][j] );
        }
    int maximum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n+1;i++)
    for(int j=0; j<n+1;j++)
    {
        if(t[i][j]>maximum)
        maximum=t[i][j];
    }
    return maximum;
}


int main()
{
    int arr[100],i,n;
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>arr[i];
    cout<<maxum(arr,n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what one of the simple test cases is? It will save a lot of time if you can.

Comment: Might also help to explain what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: What if n is 99?

Comment: Remember Hackerrank is all about testing corner-cases. You are given the constraints for the input, but they leave a wide range of cases that can still meet the constraints. Think about all forms the cases can take and still meet the constraints -- code for that.

Comment: You may want to declare the `t` array as `static` so that it doesn't occupy 10,000 * sizeof(int) bytes on the stack.  Usually, the stack is not as big as the global variable area (or the dynamic memory area).

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to put up the question link. I update it now.

Comment: What C++ reference says to use the non-standard include file `bits/stdc++.h`?  Your code only needs to `#include <iostream>`; kind of a waste of build time to use the other two.

Comment: FYI, using descriptive variable names has negligible impact on the build process, but impares reading of code.  You have at least 26^32 possible combinations of letters for variable names, so use more descriptive names.

Comment: I was actually trying to use some other DS, but then refrained myself. I forgot to remove it from the code.

Comment: According to the question, the constraint is that `n` can range from 1 to 10000, yet your `arr` array only has room for 100 numbers.

Comment: Also, if you take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63046559/code-submission-on-spoj-gives-runtime-error-sigabrt/63048464#63048464), and did some changes to the code [like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85bf0c170ec8ea80), the test case that fails is revealed to you.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm is just wrong. For instance given the input from the first test case

```
5
3 7 4 6 5
```

The correct answer is 13 (7+6) but your code outputs 25 (3+7+4+6+5).

It seems haven't implemented the requirement that the members of the maximal subset be **non-adjacent**.

Comment: I ran the same test cases in my Dev C++ and it gave 13 as output. What is going on here?

Comment: I've no idea. Here's my test case https://godbolt.org/z/fbGaKn

Comment: I actually wrote a recursive version of it and with my little knowledge of DP I tried to convert it into this. That actually worked on my machine but here it shows different answers. Can you try and run it on your machine and verify?

Comment: I don't get it. Is Dev C++ flawed then?

Comment: @cyberhawk I've just run the code on my local machine, same wrong result, 25.

Comment: @cyberhawk Seems much more likely that you are making some mistake somewhere, But I have no idea what that is.

Comment: I can confirm that the result for that test case is 25 on my machine.

Comment: @cyberhawk The posted code seems entirely predictable, it should produce the same result anywhere. So you must be running different code, or using different input, some how

Comment: Ok, so there was some problem with the software. It was running some other file I don't know how. I'm sorry to bother you, it was such a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your code exhibits undefined behaviour at least for larger inputs. Example:

```
g++ -O3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++17 -fno-exceptions -fsanitize=address a.cpp
yes 100 | ./a.out
```

Triggers asan to complain, although the input is valid according to the constraints specified in the link your provide.

```
==298664==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7ffce142a650 at pc 0x55697440f74d bp 0x7ffce14209c0 sp 0x7ffce14209b8
WRITE of size 4 at 0x7ffce142a650 thread T0
    #0 0x55697440f74c in maxum(int*, int) (/tmp/a.out+0x174c)
    #1 0x55697440f26c in main (/tmp/a.out+0x126c)
    #2 0x7fc97926acc9 in __libc_start_main ../csu/libc-start.c:308
    #3 0x55697440f3a9 in _start (/tmp/a.out+0x13a9)

[rest of asan output omitted]
```