# Modify hash value on replacing a single character in string (c++)

Tags: c++, string, hash, polynomials

I am using a polynomial hash function to calculate the hash value of a string (consisting of only lowercase english letters) as follows:

```
int SZ = 105, P = 31;
long long M = 1e12 + 9;
vector <long long> pw;

pw.resize(SZ, 1);
for(int i = 1; i < SZ; i++) {
   pw[i] = (pw[i - 1] * P) % M;
}

long long calculateHash(string &s) {
    long long h = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        h = (h + (s[i] - 'a' + 1) * pw[i]) % M;
    }
    
    return h;
}
```

I don't want to re-calculate the hash of the entire string in O(N) time when I have to replace just one character at any given position. So inorder to do this in O(1) time, I do the following operation:

```
long long h1 = calculateHash(s1);
long long h2 = calculateHash(s2);

// Only one character differs in `s1` and `s2` at index `idx`

// Modifying hash for h1 to incorporate s2[idx] and removing s1[idx]
h1 = (h1 + ((s2[idx] - s1[idx]) * pw[idx])) % M;
```

Now when I check `h1 == h2`, it should be equal ideally, right? It does work for smaller strings but fails at times, I get negative values for `h1`, not sure if this is an overflow issue or `((s2[idx] - s1[idx]) * pw[idx])` is more negative causing h1 to fall below zero.

Could anyone, suggest a way to re-calculate the hash in O(1) time when only one character is changed? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `h1 === h2` -- C++ is not JavaScript.  There is no "triple equal" in C++.

Comment: Ah! blame the butterfly keyword on my macbook :#

Comment: *I don't want to re-calculate the hash of the entire string when I have to replace just one character* -- Doesn't this defeat the purpose of what a hash function is supposed to do?  You change the string in any way, you should recalculate the hash value.

Comment: I'm sorry, the wording was misleading, I meant re-calulating it in O(1) time rather parse the entire string and re-calucate each time in O(N)

Comment: *consisting of only lowercase english letters* -- Where is the check for this?  You just assumed that all the characters are all lower case, but there is no proof.  Also, you should put together a [mcve], where all we need is to copy the code *without having to change a single line*, paste it into a compiler, and see the results.  As far as generating long strings, this [string fuzzer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63046559/code-submission-on-spoj-gives-runtime-error-sigabrt/63048464#63048464) could generate a long random string of all english lower-case.

Comment: I'm looking to solve this problem for only lowercase English letters

Comment: But you ran your program, right?  So my previous comment still stands -- how do you know that the string(s) you are testing with are all lower-case English strings?  What if the string you tested had a stray, non-English character?

Comment: https://ideone.com/y1DrF0 @PaulMcKenzie find the entire code here for your reference, you can see the case with long strings has a negative hash value

Comment: One issue is that you are using signed integers instead of unsigned.  Use `uint64_t` instead of `long long`.  You could have seen this if you simply outputted the intermediate value: `long long test = (s2[idx] - s1[idx]) * pw[idx];`, and observed it is negative.

Comment: I should solve your problem if you use: h1 = (h1 + M+ ((s2[idx] - s1[idx]) * pw[idx])) % M;
The C++ modulo doesnt do the right things if the values get negative.

Comment: An additional advice: Why do you subtract 'a' from the ascii value? If you dont do that, you could hash any string without problems.

Comment: Oh, I notice that your pw can be as big as M, so it is not sufficient to add M one time, so its better to do: h1 = (((h1 + ((s2[idx] - s1[idx]) * pw[idx])) % M)+M)%M;
That should give always the correct positive modulo.

Comment: yeah for 2 characters you'll have O(2) time

Comment: @gerum `h1 = (((h1 + ((s2[idx] - s1[idx]) * pw[idx])) % M)+M)%M;` this worked for me! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle your idea of changing the resulting value ist correct, but what you need is a modulo operator, which result is always positiv, also for negativ input numbers.

To emulate this behaviour with C++ modulo you could do the following:

```
long long tmp=(h1 + ((s2[idx] - s1[idx]) * pw[idx])) % M;
h1=(tmp+M)%M;
```

The first line is the same operation you have done, an the second line make the result positiv, because `tmp` could not be less than `-M` after the C++ modulo operation. The additional modulo is needed to assure that the number keeps smaller that `M`, even if `tmp` was already positiv.